# BigFloat in julia

Tags: julia

I can't load the bigFloat package into julia (oddly enough, neither can the ArbFloat package).
when I do:

```
using BigFloat

a = big"1.000000000000000000001"
b = big"1.000000000000000000002"

c = a + b
@show c
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package BigFloat not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("BigFloat")` to install the BigFloat package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1163 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:223 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1144
```

I reinstalled julia and it didn't solve the problem.
I also tried to install the BigFloat package as requested in the terminal, but without success.
wanted to return  `c = 2.000000000000000000000000000000003.
Furthermore, I need a package that works with 250 decimal places of precision. I am trying to use bigFloat, but I couldn't install it. I couldn't install the AbsFloat package either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigFloat` isn't a package. if you just remove that line it will work.